# Why is my dataframe being treated as if it's empty?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I'm quite new to using Excel with python and most of my code has been adjusted versions of the little sources I have found online. I have managed to figure out how to store entries from text boxes on tkinter (as shown below) and it stores them in an excel file like so:
[Sample of the excel file containing strings inputted from the user in a tkinter textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btg3h.png)

```
def storeentries():
        today = date.today()

        #Stores entries as variables
        deed = deed_text.get(1.0, END)
        improve = improve_text.get(1.0, END)
        XP = XP_text.get(1.0, END)
        entry_date = today.strftime("%d/%m/%y")

        #Use a dictionary to populate a dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[(entry_date)],
                           "Type":[("Evening")],
                           "GoodDeed":[(deed)],
                           "Improvements":[(improve)],
                           "Experiences":[(XP)]})

        #Append the dataframe results to the current excel file
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"entries.xlsx")
        sheet = workbook["Sheet1"]
        for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, header = False,
                                     index = False):
            sheet.append(row)
        workbook.save(r"entries.xlsx")
        workbook.close()
```

I am trying to find a working way of printing the values from the database according to the date inputted by the user (see below), thus filtering the excel file.

```
def viewentries():
    df = pd.read_excel("entries.xlsx")
    if df.empty == True:
        print("No Data Available for Extraction")
    else:
        entries = df[(df.Date == desired_date)]
        print(entries)
```

Even thought I have tried using an if statement to prevent the entries from being printed if the dataframe is empty, it still always returns the following:
"Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Type, Input 1, Input 2, Input 3]
Index: []."

Is there any way to fix this so it returns the whole column for the corresponding date?

Comment: Can you show an example of the data in the df? What is in the desired_date variable?

Comment: This part might be the culprit: `df[(df.Date == desired_date)]`. Pandas is likely searching along the index for True/False index values instead of using your criteria as a filter. Try this instead: `entries = df.loc[(df['Date'] == desired_date), :]`.

Comment: @que The data in the dataframe is drawn from tkinter text boxes. For example, gooddeed could just be a string consisting of "My good deed today:" followed by whatever the user inputted after that. The desired_date is another example of this where a textbox is used to get a date from the user in the form dd/mm/yy (the same form it is inputted into the excel file) in an attempt to filter the excel file by date.

Comment: @StevenS I did think that part was probably causing the issue but after implementing your suggestion the issue is still there. Do you think it could be an error with how I'm implementing the data into the excel file?

Comment: Maybe, but also check that your date column is in the same format at your desired date value. If they have different string formats or one is actually stored as a date type, then you're not going to get matches, resulting in an empty dataframe.